# Jquery clone, replace number in id and name attributes

Tags: jquery, replace, clone

I realise this question is similar to some that have been asked before and it's possible I'm not getting it because it's 9pm at night but I'd love to get a little pointer on how to fix the problem.  I know where I'm going wrong I just don't know how to fix it:

I'm cloning a table row with 4 select boxes and I want to clone the id's and names but increment the id's by one.  This is what i've got at the moment.

```
$(document).on("click", "#new_item", function() {
    var rowCount = $("#widget_location_options tbody>tr:last select").attr("id").match(/\d+/);
    var rowCount1 = rowCount*1 + 1;
    var row = $("#widget_location_options tbody>tr:last").clone(true);
    $("select option:selected", row).attr("selected", false);
    $("select", row).attr("name", $("select", row).attr("name").replace(/\d+/, rowCount1) );
    $("select", row).attr("id", $("select", row).attr("id").replace(/\d+/, rowCount1) );
    row.insertAfter("#widget_location_options tbody>tr:last");
});
```

The problem is that it's taking the id & name of the first select and correctly incrementing the id but appying it to all selects which isn't what I want.

For clarity the HTML of the row I'm cloning looks like this:

```
<tr>
<td><select id="arr_widget_location[1][position_id]" name="arr_widget_location[1][position_id]">
<option value="value">label</option>
</select></td>

<td><select id="arr_widget_location[1][position_id]" name="arr_widget_location[1][position_id]">
<option value="value">label</option>
</select></td>

<td><select id="arr_widget_location[1][position_id]" name="arr_widget_location[1][position_id]">
<option value="value">label</option>
</select></td>

<td><select id="arr_widget_location[1][position_id]" name="arr_widget_location[1][position_id]">
<option value="value">label</option>
</select></td></tr>
```

Hope someone can point out where I'm going horribly wrong!

Many thanks

Comment: Please setup a jsfiddle

Answer (score 9, accepted):

@Mark F, you gave me a hint at the right direction - thanks.  The actual solution looks like this:

```
$(document).on("click", "#new_item", function() {
    ...

    $(row).find("select").each(function(){
        $(this).attr("name", $(this).attr("name").replace(/\d+/, rowCount1) );
    });
    $(row).find("select").each(function(){
        $(this).attr("id", $(this).attr("id").replace(/\d+/, rowCount1) );
    });


    ...
});
```

Amazing what a good nights sleep and a nudge in the right direction can achieve.

Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

you're selecting all `select` elements in addition to the row, and changing all of the names and ids.

```
$("select", row).attr("name", $("select", row).attr("name").replace(/\d+/, rowCount1) );
$("select", row).attr("id", $("select", row).attr("id").replace(/\d+/, rowCount1) );
```

It looks like you're trying to get each `select` in the row you cloned, something like this.

```
$(row).find("select").attr("name", $("select", row).attr("name").replace(/\d+/, rowCount1) );
```